# Dotnet new fails - Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException

Tags: .net, visual-studio, templates, visual-studio-2017

I am using dotnet new to build/create new web application based on custom template.

If the csproj has the following line it fails with the following exception

The file does not exist at this location.  So right now I have to remove the above line to build the template then once, then I can use dotnet new with out getting this exception.

```
   Unhandled Exception: Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The imported project "C:\Program Fi   les\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.  
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject(String errorSubCategoryResourceName, IEle
mentLocation elementLocation, String resourceName, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.ProjectErrorUtilities.ThrowInvalidProject(IElementLocation elementLocation, String
resourceName, Object arg0)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpression(String directoryO
fImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, String unescapedExpression, Boolean throwOnFileNotExistsErro
r, List`1& imports)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImportsFromUnescapedImportExpressionConditioned(String
 directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImportElement importElement, String unescapedExpression, List`1& projects, Boo
lean throwOnFileNotExistsError)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.ExpandAndLoadImports(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImport
Element importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.EvaluateImportElement(String directoryOfImportingFile, ProjectImpor
tElement importElement)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.PerformDepthFirstPass(ProjectRootElement currentProjectOrImport)
   at Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Evaluator`4.Evaluate()
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectInstance.Initialize(ProjectRootElement xml, IDictionary`2 globalPropertie
s, String explicitToolsVersion, String explicitSubToolsetVersion, Int32 visualStudioVersionFromSolution, BuildPa
rameters buildParameters, ILoggingService loggingService, BuildEventContext buildEventContext)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectInstance..ctor(String projectFile, IDictionary`2 globalProperties, String
 toolsVersion, String subToolsetVersion, ProjectCollection projectCollection)
   at Microsoft.Build.Execution.ProjectInstance..ctor(String projectFile)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Common.SlnFileExtensions.AddProject(SlnFile slnFile, String fullProjectPath)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Sln.Add.AddProjectToSolutionCommand.Run(String fileOrDirectory)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.DotNetTopLevelCommandBase.<>c__DisplayClass10_1.<RunCommand>b__0()
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.DotNetTopLevelCommandBase.RunCommand(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Sln.SlnCommand.Run(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, ITelemetry telemetryClient)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Do note, that once I open the web application with vs.net 2017 it will then add this line into the csproj automatically.

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

Comment: Note also, i do not have this file either on my workstation The imported project "C:\Program Fi
les\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets